# Is there any way to try login with more than one credential in cypress

Tags: authentication, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I'm testing the user settings with cypress. I want to reset the password in before block so that even if the test change the password. Before running it must be able to reset the password to default.

I have implemented the reset password spec and the login command:

```js
    (<any>cy)
      .login(
        Cypress.env("GATEWAY_URL") + "auth/get_token/",
        "prashidi174@gmail.com",
        "aeropass"
      )
      .then(function(token: string) {
        authToken = token;
        if (authToken !== "") {
          return cy.request({
            url: ("some url"),
            headers: {
              Authorization: authToken
            }
          });
        } else {
          (<any>cy)
            .login(
              url,
              "prashidi174@gmail.com",
              "aeropass"
            )
            .then(function(token: string) {
              authToken = token;
              return cy.request({,
                headers: {
                  Authorization: authToken
                }
              });
            });
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        cy.visit("aeroview");
      });
```

I want to be able to catch the if the login fails with the wrong credential then try to login with other creadential.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do. 1. Are you trying to test two scenario's at once (first failing login, second succeed login)? 2. Are you trying to test a successful login, but with a retry if the first login fails? Or are you trying to accomplish something else?

Comment: I want to test a successful login, but with a retry, if the first login fails